# Moving div inside a div with four buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a school project, I have to create a big rectangle and a small rectangle inside the big rectangle. Then I have to create four buttons to move the small rectangle inside the big rectangle (10px).

I'm pretty new in JS so I don´t know how to start.

If someone could give me a suggestion how to start it would be very helpful.

```css
#bigd {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#move {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigd" style="width:1000px; height:600px;">
  <div id="move" style="left:450px; top:260px; width: 40px; height: 40px;"> </div>

</div>
<button type="button" onclick="left()">Links</button>
<button type="button" onclick="right()">Rechts</button>
<button type="button" onclick="up()">Auf</button>
<button type="button" onclick="down()">Ab</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to close one of the style statements with a `}`. If you click edit, scroll down and click "edit above snippet" you can add the JavaScript you tried. Also Give the small box some colour or content

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start. Make sure you call the selectors the same as in the attribute

move = bewegen

Try the rest yourself. Tip: Use .top

```js
const box = document.getElementById("move");
const step = 10;
// We just use left in both cases
const left = () => {
  let lft = parseInt(box.style.left)
  if (lft >= document.getElementById("bigd").offsetLeft+step) box.style.left = (lft-step)+"px";
};  
const right = () => {
  let lft = parseInt(box.style.left)
  if (lft <= document.getElementById("bigd").width-step) box.style.left = (lft+step)+"px";
};
```

```css
#bigd {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#move {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="bigd" style="width:5000px; height:400px;">
  <div id="move" style="left:450px; top:260px; width: 40px; height: 40px;">Box</div>

</div>
<button type="button" onclick="left()">Links</button>
<button type="button" onclick="right()">Rechts</button>
<button type="button" onclick="up()">Auf</button>
<button type="button" onclick="down()">Ab</button>
```

Comment: Thank you:) my Code works now. Do you have an idea how to keep the smoll rectangle inside the big rectangle? so that it doesn't go outside the big rectangle

Comment: You also want to look for offsetLeft

Comment: I tried it with if (left < 0) { console.log(can't go any further) }

Comment: Remember to parseInt the value since it has "px" on the end

Comment: I m sorry for taking your time but the console shows me an error. I tried this: if (left < 0 && left > height){ console.log('can't go any further')}

Comment: have a look. I am not great a positioning